# How can I reduce margin's value of the width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my code:

```css
    div{
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 20px;
    }
    span{
      display: table;
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      margin-left:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

As you see, green box is out of red box in the right side. that's because of `20px` margin left which is applied on the red box.

How can I keep both that margin and *the green box into the red box* ?

---

**Note:** The most of my website's users use old browsers. So I don't want to use `calc()`.

Comment: Just remove `width: 100%`

Comment: @MuhammadUsman I've edited my question. In current version, removing `width` doesn't give me the expected result.

Comment: Well, my variant was not for your current version. However remove `margin-left` from child and add `padding-left` on parent. Also add `box-sizing: border-box`.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman thank you. Just should I add `box-sizing: border-box` to which element? either child or parent? btw, it works without `box-sizing`. So is adding it mandatory?

Comment: It should be on child having `width: 100%` + `border`. Otherwise total width of element will be `100% + 1px`. And your element will slightly overflow the parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
span{
  display: table;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `width: 100%`:

```
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
span{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: thank you .. but sorry, I've written `display` property wrong in my question. I edited it. Please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove width

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
span{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you .. but sorry, I've written `display` property wrong in my question. I edited it. Please take a look at it again.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```css
    div{
      border: 1px solid red;
      height: 20px;
    }
    span{
      display: block;
      border: 1px solid green;
      height: 10px;
      width: auto;
      margin-left:20px;
      margin-right:20px;
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use inherit;

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
}
span{
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  width: inherit;
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: What difference will it make if `width` is not used at all?

Comment: thank you .. but sorry, I've written `display` property wrong in my question. I edited it. Please take a look at it again.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman the width defaults to auto if not specified, meaning it grows and shrinks according to the number of elements in it

Comment: @Azola No, a block level element always take full available width.

Comment: @MuhammadUsman Thanks. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements explains further, meaning width property is obsolete essentially in such an instance

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this wont fit you, as I'm modifying more than I should, but may be useful...

If you display the span as block instead of as a table, and change your margin for flowless position, you can achieve what you look for, but this may affect the relation of this items to their enviroment.

```css
  div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

span {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  left:20px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Read please,he wants table

Comment: He edited his post, first was display:block, now is display:table,he wants table